# Linq query of of two objects with nested array

Tags: linq

I have two objects pulled from from two separate JSON files. One is the source, the other is a reference to look up specific data from the source.

Source JSON:

```
 {
    "options": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "product_id": 1,
            "size": "S",
            "color": "red"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "product_id": 1,
            "size": "M",
            "color": "red"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "product_id": 1,
            "size": "L",
            "color": "red"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "product_id": 1,
            "size": "XL",
            "color": "red"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "product_id": 1,
            "size": "S",
            "color": "blue"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "product_id": 1,
            "size": "M",
            "color": "blue"
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "product_id": 1,
            "size": "L",
            "color": "blue"
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "product_id": 1,
            "size": "XL",
            "color": "blue"
        }
    ]
}
```

Lookup JSON:

```
{
    "product": {
        "styles": [
            {
                "color": "red",
                "options": [1,2,3,4]
            },
            {
                "color": "blue",
                "options": [5,6,7,8]
            }
        ]
    } 
}
```

Both are deserialized to C# models.

I need to get a list of distinct sizes across all options, so I'm querying like so:

```
var sizes = (from o in options
             from s in product.styles
             from ss in s.optionIds
             where ss == o.id
             select new Size
             {
                name = v.size,
                optionIds = // needs to be an array with all option ids 
             }
             ).ToList().GroupBy(ps => ps.name).Select(ps => ps.First()).ToList();
```

The from/where section works as expected and I get a list or distinct sizes, however, I also need to list all option ids in the new Size object...see comment in code.

The result array I'm expecting:

```
[
    {
        "name": "S",
        "optionIds": [1,5]
    },
    {
        "name": "M",
        "optionIds": [2,6]
    },
    {
        "name": "L",
        "optionIds": [3,7]
    },
    {
        "name": "XL",
        "optionIds": [4,8]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, your "lookup JSON" doesn't include any information that isn't already found in the source, so there's no point muddying the water with that data.

```
var sizes = options
    .GroupBy(o => o.size, o => o.id)
    .Select(g => new Size {name = g.Key, options = g.ToList()})
    .ToList()
```

Comment: Not quite. These are simplified examples to focus on the type of joining I need to do, there is other data on source that's pulled based the option ID in source. Sorry, I probably should have clarified that. Ultimately, the source JSON is the source of truth for option IDs and all related data, so that's why there is a look up JSON file to define what to pull from source.

Comment: @Scott: Can you update your question to show data on the result array you're expecting which needs to come from the lookup JSON?